# Category entity relationship / subtype relationships design

Tags: sql-server, database-design, subtypes

I am looking to implement a generic comment and file attachment facility within a web application which would be used across various parts and allow users to provide comments and add attachments to different entities.

Whilst looking for a suitable solution I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112831/implementing-comments-and-likes-in-database/8113064#8113064) and I wanted to check I am fully understanding the implementation of this approach and understand the potential pitfalls.

Using a schema similar to the one below the `ContractId`, `ContractLineId` and `VariationId` values, along with any future entities, would be generated using a `SEQUENCE` (using SQL Server 2012) and each generated value would be stored in the `Entity` table along with its `EntityType`.

The use of the `SEQUENCE` across multiple entities would allow for a single `Comment` and `Attachment` table and therefore a `Comment` or `Attachment` could be created against a `Contract`, `ContractLine` and `Variation` and any future entities.

The `Entity` table is used as a sort of junction table (or some other term) and would allow queries to return all `Attachments` against particular entity type(s).

Though things get a little messy if attachments against multiple entities need to be returned along with some information about the entity. For example, if all comments made by a user were to be queried along with the name of the entity the comment was against.

Am I going down the right path or should this be avoided.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this looks pretty reasonable for a system in which a user can add comments or attachments associated with a contract, a specific line of the contract, or a proposed modification to a line of a contract.

Since you asked for potential shortcomings or pitfalls, here are a few you might consider:

- Without knowing much about your system, it seems strange that a variation must apply to only one contract line.  Is there ever a case where a variation might apply to multiple lines?  And then a user might want to comment on the multi-line variation in its entirety?  If so, this case doesn't appear to be handled  right now.
- It's surprising that there aren't any columns other than `EntityType` that are common across all entities.  Perhaps there should be an `EntityName` column rather than separate columns `ContractName`, `ContractLineName`, and `VariationName`?  This would make the example query you describe in your question far simpler.
- The data model  does not strictly enforce that the `Variation` contains logically consistent data.  It stores both a `ContractId` and a `ContractLineId`.  The foreign keys for these columns enforce that each is valid independently, but allow for a `ContractLineId` to be inserted that comes from the incorrect `ContractId` (that is, different than the `ContractId` for that `ContractLineId` in the `ContractLine` table).  One option to address this is to remove the `ContractId` column from the `Variation` table.